# How do I get my godep dependencies in my ...project_folder/Godeps/_workspace/?

Tags: go, godeps

I was given source code with a *Godeps/Godeps.json* file. From what I understand is I need to get my dependancies into *...project_folder/Godeps/_workspace/src*.

**My Go Path:**
/users/me/work

I used *godep restore* which downloaded all the dependancies to */users/me/work/src*

Am I supposed to manipulate to the GoPATH so that *godep restore* puts it where I want? Or do I need to manually copy it after? Or am I just using the wrong command?

Comment: Which commands did you use? I typically run: `godep save ./...` and it creates the _workspace folder and copies every dependency in _workspace/src/

Comment: @AbelardoMendoza whats ur GOPATH set to? and where is your project relative to it? Also what working directory do you run the command (if it matters)?

Comment: $GOPATH: ~/go  Project: $GOPATH/src/github.com/user/project/ .. and just run the command `godep save ./...` inside of $GOPATH/src/github.com/user/project/

Comment: Also, is your **GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT** environment variable set?